# function to convert amount into Indian words (Crores, Lakhs, Thousands ...) in R language

Tags: r

I need a function in R language to convert amount into Indian words in [crore, lakh, thousand etc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system#Names_of_numbers)...

For example:

- function(3257) should generate: Three Thousand Two Hundred and Fifty Seven;
- function(473257) should generate: Four Lakh Seventy Three Thousand Two Hundred and Fifty Seven;
- function(12473257) should generate: One Crore Twenty Four Lakh Seventy Three Thousand Two Hundred and Fifty Seven

Plenty of working VBA functions can be found on the internet for use with Microsoft Excel and Access but I was unable to find a similar function in R language.

**Edit:** Example how to do it in English words: https://github.com/ateucher/useful_code/blob/master/R/numbers2words.r

Comment: look at `english::as.english`. Obviously you would need to edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I have figured it out myself. Interested users may test and report bugs, if any.

```
# function to convert number to words in Indian counting system
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system#Names_of_numbers

# number always rounded; multiple numbers also accepted as vector
# currently handles numbers upto 15 digits but can be easily extended

# Credit: A big THANKS to Mr. John Fox.
# His function to convert number to English words can be found at:
# http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/2715.html

SpellIndianNumber <- function(x){

  helper <- function(x){

    digits <- rev(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]])
    nDigits <- length(digits)

    # function meant to handle numbers upto 15 digits only
    if(nDigits > 15) stop("Number is too large!")

    # single digit cases: 1 to 9
    if (nDigits == 1) as.vector(ones[digits])

    # two digits cases: 10 to 99
    else if (nDigits == 2)
      if (x <= 19) as.vector(teens[digits[1]]) # for 10 to 19
    else trim(paste(tens[digits[2]], # for 20 to 99
                    Recall(as.numeric(digits[1]))))

    # three digits cases: 100 to 999
    else if (nDigits == 3) trim(paste(ones[digits[3]], "Hundred", 
                                      Recall(makeNumber(digits[2:1]))))

    # four & five digits cases: handling thousands
    else if (nDigits <= 5){
      thousands <- x %/% 1e3
      remainder <- x %% 1e3
      trim(paste(Recall(thousands), "Thousand", Recall(remainder)))
    }

    # six & seven digits cases: handling lakhs
    else if (nDigits <= 7){
      lakhs <- x %/% 1e5
      remainder <- x %% 1e5
      trim(paste(Recall(lakhs), "Lakh", Recall(remainder)))
    }

    # eight & nine digits cases: handling crores
    else if (nDigits <= 9){
      crores <- x %/% 1e7
      remainder <- x %% 1e7
      trim(paste(Recall(crores), "Crore", Recall(remainder)))
    }

    # ten & eleven digits cases: handling arabs
    else if (nDigits <= 11){
      arabs <- x %/% 1e9
      remainder <- x %% 1e9
      trim(paste(Recall(arabs), "Arab", Recall(remainder)))
    }

    # twelve & thirteen digits cases: handling kharabs
    else if (nDigits <= 13){
      kharabs <- x %/% 1e11
      remainder <- x %% 1e11
      trim(paste(Recall(kharabs), "Kharab", Recall(remainder)))
    }

    # fourteen & fifteen digits cases: handling neels
    else if (nDigits <= 15){
      neels <- x %/% 1e13
      remainder <- x %% 1e13
      trim(paste(Recall(neels), "Neel", Recall(remainder)))
    }
  }

  trim <- function(text){
    gsub("^\ ", "", gsub("\ *$", "", text))
  }

  makeNumber <- function(...) as.numeric(paste(..., collapse=""))

  opts <- options(scipen=100)
  on.exit(options(opts))

  ones <- c("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
            "Eight", "Nine")
  names(ones) <- 0:9

  teens <- c("Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen",
             "Sixteen", " Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen")
  names(teens) <- 0:9

  tens <- c("Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy",
            "Eighty", "Ninety")
  names(tens) <- 2:9

  x <- round(x)

  if (length(x) > 1) return(sapply(x, helper))
  helper(x)
}

# Examples:

# > SpellIndianNumber(83720834)
# [1] "Eight Crore Thirty Seven Lakh Twenty Thousand Eight Hundred Thirty Four"

# > SpellIndianNumber(1283720834)
# [1] "One Arab Twenty Eight Crore Thirty Seven Lakh Twenty Thousand Eight Hundred Thirty Four"

# > SpellIndianNumber(653234532342345)
# [1] "Sixty Five Neel Thirty Two Kharab Thirty Four Arab Fifty Three Crore Twenty Three Lakh Forty Two Thousand Three Hundred Forty Five"

# > SpellIndianNumber(c(5,10,87))
# [1] "Five"         "Ten"          "Eighty Seven"

# > SpellIndianNumber(11:15)
# [1] "Eleven"   "Twelve"   "Thirteen" "Fourteen" "Fifteen" 

# Number Zero will appear as a zero length string
# > SpellIndianNumber(0)
# [1] ""

# > SpellIndianNumber(c(12,0,87))
# [1] "Twelve"       ""             "Eighty Seven"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Function to Convert Amount in Number to Digits in Indian Standard upto 12 digits**

```
function GetAmountInWords(Amount) {
    var nums = parseFloat(Amount).toFixed(2).toString().split('.');
    var AmountInWords = '';
    if (nums.length > 0 && parseInt(nums[0]) > 0) {
    AmountInWords += ReturnAmountInWords(nums[0]) + 'Rupees '
    }
    if (nums.length == 2 && parseInt(nums[1]) > 0) {
        var Paisa = ReturnAmountInWords(nums[1]);
        AmountInWords += ((AmountInWords.trim().length > 0) ? 'and ' : '') + Paisa + 'Paisa ';
    }
    return (AmountInWords.length > 0) ? AmountInWords + 'Only.' : '';
}

var a = ['', 'One ', 'Two ', 'Three ', 'Four ', 'Five ', 'Six ', 'Seven ', 'Eight ', 'Nine ', 'Ten ', 'Eleven ', 'Twelve ', 'Thirteen ', 'Fourteen ', 'Fifteen ', 'Sixteen ', 'Seventeen ', 'Eighteen ', 'Nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety'];

function ReturnAmountInWords(num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 12) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000000' + num).substr(-12).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return;
    var AmountStr = '';
    AmountStr += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'Thousand ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'Hundred ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[1] != 0 || n[2] != 0 || n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'Crore ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'Lakh ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[5] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'Thousand ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[6] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[6])] || b[n[6][0]] + ' ' + a[n[6][1]]) + 'Hundred ' : '';
    AmountStr += (n[7] != 0) ? ((AmountStr != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[7])] || b[n[7][0]] + ' ' + a[n[7][1]]) + '' : '';
    return AmountStr;
}
```